# SOLR: size of term dictionary and how to prune it

Tags: solr, lucene

Two related questions:

**Q1.** I would like to find out the term dictionary size (in number of terms) of a core.

One thing I do know how to do is to list the file size of *.tim. For example:

```
> du -ch *.tim | tail -1
1,3G    total
```

But how can I convert this to number of terms? Even a rough estimate would suffice.

**Q2.** A typical technique in search is to "prune" the index by removing all rare (very low frequency) terms. The objective is not to prune the size of the index, but the size of the actual term dictionary. What would be the simpler way to do this in SOLR, or programatically in SOLRj?

More exactly: I wish to eliminate these terms (tokens) from an existing index (term dictionary and all the other places in the index). The result should be similar to 1) adding the terms to a stop word list, 2) re-indexing an entire collection, 3) removing the terms from the stop word list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get information in the Schema Browser page and click in "Load Term info", in the luke admin handler https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler and also, in then stats component https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component.
2. To prune the index, you could do it by do a facet of the field, and get the terms with low frecuency. Then, get the docs and update the document without this term (this could be difficult because it's depends the analyzers and tokenizers of your field). Also, you can use the lucene libraries to open the index and do it programmatically.

Comment: are you sure this will remove them form the term dictionary? perhaps after an optimze?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think in a first step, the terms will be marked as deleted but not removed from the term index, and after an optimize, or a commit that cause a merge of the segments, the term index will be updated.

Comment: I confirmed that deleting (+commit) the documents does not remove them form the dictionary, but an optimize afterwards will.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check the number and distribution of your terms with the AdminUI under the collection's *Schema Browser* screen. You need to Load Term Info:
   [image]

Or you can use [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) which allows you to look inside the Lucene index.

2. It is not clear what you mean to 'remove'. You can add them to the stopwords in the analyzer chain for example if you want to avoid indexing them.